# Inserting different values in php echo

Tags: php, html, authentication

I have a login script with a Twitter-like posting script and I tried to insert the user name into the posts but that didn't work. They are both using the same database but I can't figure out why. Here is the  php.

```
    <?php

session_start();

require_once 'database.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){

echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['user'];

?>


<?php
$posts = show_posts($_SESSION['userid']);

if (count($posts)){
?>
```

Now the posts part

```
<table class="imagetable">
<table align="center" border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' width='300'>
<td background="cell-blue.jpg"> 
<?php
foreach ($posts as $key => $list){
    echo "<tr valign='middle'>\n";

    echo "<td>".".$_SESSION['user']" . "<p>'s BFFL is</p>".$list['body'] ."<br/>\n  "; 
    echo "<small>".$list['stamp'] ."<hr>"."</small></td>\n"; 
    echo "</tr>\n"; 
}
?>
</table>
```

I'm a noob to php, and I can't get why it's not working... I just want the name of the user to be in the post.

Comment: Could you please just show the relevant code?

Comment: here, fixed it. Now its relevant

Comment: You are outputting your form before your HTML tags.  Also, is it proper to use session_start() twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an extra period (concat operator) before your session variable.  I cleaned it up for you.

```
echo "<td>" . $_SESSION['user'] . "<p>'s BFFL is</p>" . $list['body'] . "<br/>\n";
```